# PHP: How should I convert this inconsistent string into arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, string, delimiter

I have this string: `$delims = ',^.;:\t'` (which is used in a `preg_replace()` call).
I need two arrays .. one with those delimiters as the index (`$delimCount`), and another with those delimiters as the values (`$delimiters`).

The former will get values assigned from within a loop on the latter .. as such:

```
foreach ($delimiters as $delim) { 
    if( strpos($char, $delim) !== false) { // if the char is the delim ...
        $delimCount[$delim]++; // ... increment
    }
}
```

The way I have it now is messy, and I'd like to simply break that string into the two arrays ... but I'm getting tripped up on the `\t` delimiter (because it's the only one with two characters).
How can/should I handle that?

Comment: Why didn't you write `$delims = ",^.;:\t";` instead?

Comment: Use a double-quoted string instead. `\t` is *one* character then.

Comment: And, by the way, if you need to split some string into smaller ones with different tokens, you might be interested in [strtok](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php) function.

Comment: Yes - PHP doesn't parse special characters in strings wrapped in single quotes, only double quotes

Comment: Thanks, but if I dbl-qt the string, then my index in the `$delimiters` array becomes an interpreted tab rather than '\t' which conflicts with a later need/usage ... maybe it's time for me to look at whether that later usage REALLY **needs** it as a string or not ... maybe I can just change that code and leave this problem with the simple/elegant solution proposed.  Thanks-a-bunch.  Let me know if you have any other thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I would handle your `\t` delimiter

```
$delims = ',^.;:\t';

$i = 0;

while($i < strlen($delims)) {
    if($delims[$i] == chr(92)) {
        $delimiters[] = $delims[$i] . $delims[$i+1];
        $i = $i + 2;
    }
    else {
        $delimiters[] = $delims[$i];
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Output of $delimiters

```
Array
(
    [0] => ,
    [1] => ^
    [2] => .
    [3] => ;
    [4] => :
    [5] => \t
)
```

As far as an array with the delimiters as an index

```
foreach($delimiters as $key=>$val) {
    $delimCount[$val] = $val;
}
```

Output of $delimCount

```
Array
(
    [,] => ,
    [^] => ^
    [.] => .
    [;] => ;
    [:] => :
    [\t] => \t
)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you .. while ALL of the answers were extremely helpful, your `while` loop is the one which specifically solved the question as I posted it .. so I ticked this one as the answer. Thanks again to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

> I need two arrays .. one with those delimiters as the index ($delimCount), and another with those delimiters as the values ($delimiters).

Well, where does $delimiters come from? Did you write it yourself? If so, I'd argue you'd be better off making $delimiters an array in any case, and using implode when you use it in preg_replace.

Comment: Thanks ... believe it or not, this was extremely helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem with tabulator, then you can use ordinal number of character as the key inplace of character itself: `$delim = "\t"; $delimCount[ ord($delim) ]++;`

Handy complementary functions: [ord()](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) and [chr()](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php).

Comment: Great suggestion ... `ord()` and `chr()` were new to me .. thanks